# How to change the fontsize in the heading of the glossary

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, glossaries

I set up a glossary using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cmp}{CMP}{Common Mid Point}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Glossary}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

After running 
`name.glo -s name.ist -t name.glg -o name.gls`
in the shell, I get a nice Glossary. The heading of my glossary is automatically created to be "Glossary". This is all right, except the fact that the fontsize of my this heading is far too big, compared to the other constituents in my table of contents. 
How can I modify the fontsize with which the glossary is created?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your MWE is incomplete, so I can't see the problem. (You don't have `\begin{document}`, `\tableofcontents` or other sectional units for comparison. You also don't need to use the `acronym` package as it has no bearing on the problem, nor is it needed with `glossaries`.)

The glossary uses `\chapter` when used with the `report` class, so it uses the same font as other chapters. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[nonumberlist,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{cmp}{CMP}{Common Mid Point}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\section{Sample Section}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of table of contents]

The "Glossary" entry is the same size as the "Sample Chapter" entry.

Answer (score 1):

The `glossaries` package sets by default the glossaries as top level parts of your document, i.e., for `article`s the glossaries are `section`s, while for `report` and `book` the glossaries are `chapter`s. The title of your glossary is as big as a chapter heading should be. To make it smaller, you could make your glossary into a section, by loading it with

```
\usepackage[nonumberlist,section=section]{glossaries}
```

but be aware that then the glossary will be a section belonging to the chapter that was started before.

Comment: Dear all,
Thank you very much for your answers and sorry for the confusion.. I found an alternative: Modifying
   \printglossary[title={Glossary } ]
to
   \printglossary[title= \normalsize\textbf{Glossary } ]
does the trick. So, only the heading "Glossary" itself (i.e. the part where my glossary appears as a "chapter" within my document, like the heading "Contents" in the answer from Nicola), was to be changed.