# How to center glossary title without messing up chapter/sections?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, glossaries

My problem is that the glossary title should be normal size, bold, all caps and **centered**.

While Chapter, section and subsection must be all **left** aligned. So I cannot change section style to suit glossary because it will break the sections original style. Yes, university is specific about such thing (the ruler is my personal touch)...
I do have other glossaries, and they must all not show at ToC.

If I try to use `\printacronyms[style=long,title=\centering \uppercase\bfseries {Glossary Title}]` as suggested Benjamin comment [on this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111498/75648), it gives me an error:

```
Missing { inserted. ...ysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}
Missing } inserted. ...ysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. ...ysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}
```

If I try `\centering \printacronyms...` then chapter and section gets centered but justified with horrible spacing MS-Word-loking because of the few words, but glossary doesn't change. Like this:

[image: bogus chapter centered but glossary not]

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\selectlanguage{brazil}         

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\thechapter}{20pt}{}[\vspace{2ex}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.35cm}]
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\thesection}}{15pt}{} 

\usepackage[xindy={language=portuguese},acronym,sort=standard,nomain,nonumberlist=true,nogroupskip]{glossaries} 

\setglossarysection{subsection} 
\newacronym{pnnl}{PNNL}{Pacific Northwest National Laboratory}

\def\xindylangopt{-L lang/brazil/utf8-lang}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}


\printacronyms[style=long,title={Glossary Title}]% \centering \uppercase\bfseries {Glossary Title}]
\chapter{Chapter Title}

Text text \gls{pnnl} text text Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text 
\section{Section title}
Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The section header for each glossary is set using `\glossarysection[\glossarytoctitle]{\glossarytitle}` so you just need to redefine that command before you print the glossary. For example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\selectlanguage{brazil}         

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\bfseries\LARGE}
  {\thechapter}{20pt}{}[\vspace{2ex}\rule{\columnwidth}{0.35cm}]
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontfamily{fvs}\selectfont\bfseries}
  {\MakeUppercase{\thesection}}{15pt}{} 

\usepackage[xindy={language=portuguese},acronym,sort=standard,nomain,nonumberlist=true,nogroupskip]{glossaries} 

\setglossarysection{subsection} 
\newacronym{pnnl}{PNNL}{Pacific Northwest National Laboratory}

\def\xindylangopt{-L lang/brazil/utf8-lang}
\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{{\centering\bfseries\MakeTextUppercase{#2}\par}}

\begin{document}


\printacronyms[style=long,title={Glossary Title}]

\chapter{Chapter Title}

Text text \gls{pnnl} text text Text text text text Text text text
text Text text text text 
\section{Section title}
Text text text text Text text text text Text text text text Text
text text text 
\end{document}
```

This ignores the first argument so it doesn't get added to the table of contents, but the change to `\glossarysection` means it's no longer a sectioning command, so the definition may need adjusting.

Comment: That was fast, and works prefectly. I've tried similar commands before, but I was using `\glossaryheader` and `\glossarytitle`, which is probably why it didn't work since I defined glossary to be section right? Many thanks.

Comment: @G.Bay `\glossarysection` is the command that usually does the sectioning stuff (`\section`, `\chapter` or whatever), `\glossarytitle` is the actual title set at the start of `\printglossary` (or `\printacronyms`), and `\glossaryheader` is inserted after `\begin{theglossary}` and is redefined by the glossary styles. Many of the styles redefine `\glossaryheader` to do nothing but some, such as the `longheader` style redefine it to add header columns for a tabulated glossary. (There's also `\glossarypreamble` which is a user hook that occurs immediately after `\glossaryheader`.)

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `\glossarypreamble` occurs immediately after `\glossarysection`.